# Android - how do I open a menu when hardware menu button is pressed?

Tags: android, menu

I'm an Android newbie and I'm trying to open a menu when hardware menu button is clicked, pretty much like the Gmail menu illustrated here: http://cdn.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/nexusae0_Screenshot_2013-06-03-11-55-54.png.

I've browsed a lot and can't seem to find an answer.

The best answer I've found so far is to make my Activity override the onKeyDown method, as below:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    switch(keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            Toast.makeText(this, "HALLO!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
}
```

And that actually worked, I'm able to display the toast, but I can't seem to find a way to open a menu, like the one in the picture.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: The menu is handled automatically by the hardware button, you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to go through below link once again.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

You need not to handle menu button click explicitly to open Menu. Just try to create empty application with menu in Android studio and observe the behavior to understand more.

Good Luck!!